# Long example title overflows into the buttons

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

There is an example in https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/484/date-and-time which the title is so long it is broken into two lines. We see that part of the text are covered by the edit, share and upvote buttons.

[image: so long]

Since the buttons are above the text there is no problem in interaction. It is just ugly.

(Browser: Firefox 47.0.1, on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.)

Comment: Do you need the version in the title? You can just add the version to the example via an HTML comment...