# Long example titles in Documentation overlap other UI elements (vote arrows, flag and share icons, etc.)

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

[image: Bug in displaying elements]
[Link to documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2B%2B/1812/undefined-behavior/5921/reaching-the-end-of-a-value-returning-function-other-than-main-without-a-retur#t=201607232028572832746)

I am using Vivaldi 1.3.537.5 (Build) dev (64-bit)

Comment: That does *not* sound like something on the "supported browsers" list. :)

Comment: Reproduced with FF 47 on Win 10

Comment: And Chrome under OSX, it's not a Vivaldi thing.

Comment: Confirmed on Safari 9.1 OS X 10.11.

Comment: Reproduced on FF 45 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Related [post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328561/2451726)?

Comment: A fix is in the works. Will be live soon (need to rebuild a few things and test.)