# Vote button missing

Tags: bug, documentation

I have just added a [new example on Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/debugging/5312/introduction-to-debugging) and the voting buttons are not visible.

Maybe it happens just for very long titles. It seems related to [this issue about overflowing into the buttons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328561/long-example-title-overflows-into-the-buttons) but in my case, the button is completely invisible and maybe that only happens for items pending review.

Note how the buttons are fine for the short title ("Installation and Setup").

I'm using Firefox 47 on Windows 10.

[image: Vote buttons missing]

Comment: meta cruft: Isn't [tag:debugging] too general of a tag for documentation?

Comment: @JAL: well, I'm trying to document something useful. Maybe I'll give up. I'm also trying with [tag:windbg] and the current way does not really fit my needs.

Comment: meta meta cruft: you should update to Firefox 48

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't viewing a topic, **you're viewing a draft**. Your change must be reviewed. Once is is approved by other users and appears publicly, you'll be able to vote (but not from the draft — make sure to click "this topic" tab once it's created).

P. S. Debugging is too general. I don't think it's a good tag for Documentation.

Comment: A lot of questions on Stack Overflow are about debugging. If we managed to get helpful documentation about debugging, it might be a great help in answering questions that otherwise require very long answers.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I think it's hard to describe debugging in general. Sure, some things are common, but there're a lot of IDE-specific things, so general descriptions won't be too helpful.